# spresense LTE拡張ボードをArduinoIDEで使用時にモデムの省電力設定にする方法

Tags: spresense

1時間に数回センサー値を送りたいと考えています（送信間隔は不定期でspresenseはsleepさせずに常に待機）
Spresense SDKの開発ガイドでLTEの省電力設定が紹介されていますがArduinoIDEで設定することは出来ますか？
例えばLTEモデムにATコマンドを送って設定することはできませんか？
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E7%9C%81%E9%9B%BB%E5%8A%9B%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の記事でSpresenseのArduino上で低レイヤのSDKのAPIを使用して消電制御している例があります。
https://qiita.com/nara256/items/7cd69918f583245e3b5a

2種類の消費電力を削減する制御用APIが使えるようです。
・eDRX（extended Discontinuous Reception）：
　lte_set_edrx_sync()
・PSM（Power Saving Mode）：
　lte_set_psm_sync()
※用語の意味について参照例： https://www.ntt.com/business/lp/iot/lpwa.html

使用に当たっては、lte/lte_api.h を includeすることと、begin()メソッドを呼ぶ必要があるようです。ご参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　やりたいことズバリを解説してる記事でした　参考にします